# Copying table rows with merged cells

Tags: vba, ms-word, runtime-error

I needed to insert multiple copies of a group of rows formatted as shown below.

```
+-------------------------------------------------+
|                       1,1                       |
+-------------------------------------------------+
|         |   2,2   |         |   2,4   |         |
|   2,1   +---------+   2,3   +---------+   2,5   |
|         |   3,2   |         |   3,4   |         |
+-------------------------------------------------+
|                       4,1                       |
+-------------------------------------------------+
|         |   5,2   |         |   5,4   |         |
|   5,1   +---------+   5,3   +---------+   5,5   |
|         |   6,2   |         |   6,4   |         |
+-------------------------------------------------+
```

In case A, I needed multiple copies of rows 1-3 inserted before row 4.

In case B, I needed multiple copies of rows 4-6 inserted at the end of the table.

The table.rows(n) method doesn't work and gives the following error :

> Run-time error '5991':
>
> Cannot access individual rowsin this collection because the table has vertically merged cells

However, one can do this from the user interface, so it must be possible!

Comment: Please add your answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how I overcame the problem (tested in Word 2007 and Word 2003)

```
Sub CaseA()

    Dim D As Document, T As Table

    Set D = ActiveDocument

    Set T = D.Tables(1)     '   select the first table in the document
                '   select from the start of row 1 to the start of row 4
    D.Range(T.Cell(2, 1).Range.Start, T.Cell(4, 1).Range.Start).Select

    Selection.Copy          '   copy the rows
                            '   move the insertion point to the start of row 4
    Selection.Collapse wdCollapseEnd 

    Selection.Paste         '   insert a copy
                                    '   (can do this as many times as you want)

End Sub

Sub CaseB()

    Dim D As Document, T As Table

    Set D = ActiveDocument

    Set T = D.Tables(1)
' select from the start of row 5 to the end of the last cell present in row 6
' plus 1 character for column 5 plus 1 character to move outside the table
    D.Range(T.Cell(5, 1).Range.Start, T.Cell(6, 4).Range.End + 2).Select

    Selection.Copy          '   copy the rows
                            '   move the insertion point just outside the table
    Selection.Collapse wdCollapseEnd

    Selection.Paste         '   insert a copy

End Sub
```